# Disadvantages of using Linode VPS?

Tags: vps, linode, cons

I have been looking to find a set of disadvantages of using Linode VPS.

There does not seem to be any dedicated articles for what I have searched on the internet.

Can anyone list some disadvantages?

I'm researching the pros and cons for modern server set-ups.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using Linode for several years and I've yet to find a ton of cons... Here's a list of pros/cons just off the top of my head:

**Pros**

- Most resources for the buck
- Easy to add/remove "hardware" as needed
- Lots of the recent distros of various *nix flavors depending on your need
- Seem to always be adding new features, such as server upgrades, which help all users.
- Their support is, hands down, the best support I've ever experienced.

**Cons**

- The biggest one I've found is they limit you to two IP addresses, and you have to really justify why you need a second one.  This can be a hassle if, for whatever reason, you need more than one IP address.
- I haven't found that I've been notified when they do maintenance or have upgrades available... It's possible my settings are messed up and I could get an email, but I haven't dug that deep.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to Amazon one of the cons of Linode is that you cannot store disk images of your linode in your account.Creating images makes server setup easy, all you need to do is write the image to your new servers disk.It also makes it easy to shift servers.